# How do I install custom SharePoint Timer job on MOSS

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How do I install custom SharePoint Timer job on MOSS

Hello I created,
custom SharePoint Timer job,
Below in this document is my code.

I wrote and installed a lot of
 webparts.

But this is the first time I write
 SharePoint Timer job on MOSS.

i try to deploy it wite wspBuilder,
try to copy it to gac,
But the JOB not appear on the list JOB on
Central Administration site ,
Central Administration > Operations > Timer Job Definitions ,
how can i add it and see it on the ,

Central Administration > Operations > Timer Job Definitions 
the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
namespace WSPBuilderProject1.FeatureCode
{
    public class MyTimerJob : SPJobDefinition
    {
        public MyTimerJob()
            : base()
        {
            this.Title = "My Timer Job";
        }

        public MyTimerJob(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType targetType)
            : base(jobName, service, server, targetType)
        {
            this.Title = "My Timer Job";
        }

        public MyTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication)
            : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {
            this.Title = "My Timer Job";
        }


        public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
        {

            using (SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("/"))
            {
                SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
                mySite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists["AuditLogCalculatedData"].Items;
                int itemCount = listItems.Count;

                for (int k = 0; k < itemCount; k++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        listItems.Delete(k);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }


                    SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

                    item["FileName"] = "roi";
                    item["NumOfEntries"] = 10102;


                    item.Update();

                mySite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can  you tell use the issues you are facing ...

Comment: Webpart is an UI element. TimerJobs doesn't show any interface. What exactly do you want to achieve? What do you want your timer job to do?

Comment: Please specify the sharepoint version.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample code which can be executed on `FeatureActivated` event

```
public override void FeatureActivated (SPFeatureReceiverProperties props) {
  SPWebApplication webApp = props.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
  if (webApp == null)
    throw new SPException("Error obtaining reference to Web application.");

  // Ensure the job is not already registered.
  foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webApp.JobDefinitions)
    if (job.Name == JOB_NAME) job.Delete();

  // Install job.
  SharePointWarmupJob warmupJob = new SharePointWarmupJob(webApplication);

  // Schedule the job to run every minute all the time.
  SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
  schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
  schedule.EndSecond = 59;
  schedule.Interval = 1;
  warmupJob.Schedule = schedule;

  // Save changes.
  warmupJob.Update();
}
```

Comment: Create a feature and put this in featureactivated event of the feature

Comment: what is the using for SharePointWarmupJob  it says Error 4 The type or namespace name 'SharePointWarmupJob' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: SharePointWarmupJob is your custom timer job class. From your example it is 'MyTimerJob'. This code example answers on how to register your timer job. Use this article to see how to hook that feature activated event to your timer job feature: http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/How+to+add+a+Feature+Receiver+to+a+Feature

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

If you read down the article, there is a zipped solution file ([TaskLogger_CustomTimerJob.zip](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blogcontent/TaskLogger_CustomTimerJob.zip)) which you can use and compile yourself.

VS2008 will prompt you to convert project to 2008, just do it and compile.

### Building the project

The problem you can't build lies within file BuildSharePointPackage.Targets. MakeCabPath is not valid for your environment. My makecab.exe lies in `C:\Windows\system32` path. I tried to change path and rebuild, but it didn't work, it somehow tried to use the old location. So i just copied makecab.exe to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Cabinet SDK\bin` and it builds sucessfully.

### WSPBuilder

Also, you may want to use WSPBuilder to alleviate the pain on creating SharePoint solutions. It installs visual studio extension which you can use to make wsp file and deploy from visual studio. [Download WSPBuilder here](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/), and use [Walkthrough of the Visual Studio Add-in](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/04/08/wspbuilder-walkthrough-of-the-visual-studio-add-in.aspx)

Comment: it give me the error Error 1 The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Cabinet SDK\BIN\MAKECAB.EXE" /F BuildSharePointPackage.ddf /D CabinetNameTemplate=AndrewConnell.TaskLoggerJob.wsp /D DiskDirectory1=bin\Debug\SpPackage\" exited with code 3. AndrewConnell.TaskLoggerJob and i cant find on the internet this Microsoft Cabinet SDK to download